# Is it possible to authenticate at the same time as making a SQL query (not authenticate beforehand)

Tags: mysql, authentication, passwords

This may be a horrible idea for security but I am wondering if there is a way to authenticate an existing SQL user at the same time as making a SQL query.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE city <> 'Detroit' and ...
```

After the ellipses should be the part where the user is authenticated.
It it possible to do this in one step?

I am trying to provide useful error messages but unfortunately I am stuck using SOAP and I am having a hard time proving a user exists before making the query. Please let me know if I am totally going the wrong direction. I can get nice error messages if the database doesn't exist, but I just get vague SOAP errors if the user / password are incorrect. I would like to prove that the user / password are acceptable before making the query so I can make my program more user friendly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can from shell command line:

```
$ mysql -u user -p -e 'show databases;'
```

Just to be clear: there's **NO WAY** to execute a query **BEFORE** authentication only if maybe you use a API without auth but that is a huge security risk.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply. OK. That's what I thought. What would you recommend though? First do SOAP authentication, THEN run the SQL query from within SOAP? Sorry for being such a noob at SOAP

Comment: @pavlvsmaximvs : yes, first auth via SOAP and then exec the query its the best option you have.

Comment: I should add I can't access the database directly so unfortunately that is not an option. I wish I could. I just wondered if I could authenticate and query simultaneously.

Comment: you can authenticate and query in the same time with the command i gave you but you need to use a function like `exec` in php

Comment: Sorry it took 9 years to accept the answer. Thanks @Stephan

Comment: @SyntaxNurse better late than never 